# Prevent LaTeX from adding paragraph after blank line

Tags: tex-core, comments

I like to put a lot of comments inside my documents, even between sentences.

To make the comments more visible I would like to put a blank line between the comment and the sentence before like this:

```
This is some beautiful sample text.

% This is a comment
A blank line before the comment makes the TeX document more readable.
```

Unfortunately this leaves me with a paragraph between the two sentences. I would rather begin a new paragraph with `\par` and have no paragraph after a new line by default. Preferably I would like to set this with a global setting, as I don't want to put something like `\randomcommand` infront of the second sentence.

This is only a minor annoyance, so if it is not possible without going to great length that would also be an acceptable answer to me.

Thanks in advance if anyone takes time to answer my question.

Comment: Put a single `%` in the blank line.

Comment: It is in fact possible but the mapping of  a blank line to `\par` happens at a very deep level in TeX's parser, before any interpretation of macros happens, so changing this is likely to break a lot of code. Just putting a `%` there is a lot safer,

Comment: Blank line has important function: it start new paragraph. Redefining it is dangerous.

Comment: Note that asking for this shows that you are thinking of tex as you would think of a language in which white space is ignorable and can be used to layout the source code for style. In TeX white space is almost always significant, you can _change_ that interpretation but that is changing the language.

Comment: To be on the safe side, consider that `\par` ***ends*** a paragraph, rather than start it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is in fact possible but the mapping of  a blank line to `\par` happens at a very deep level in TeX's parser, before any interpretation of macros happens, so changing this is likely to break a lot of code. Just putting a `%` there is a lot safer,

If you really want to try this, see the effect of `\endlinechar` to make tex add a normal space at the end of a line. **This will almost certainly break something**.

[image]

```
\endlinechar=32

This is some beautiful sample text.

% This is a comment
A blank line before the comment makes the TeX document more readable.


\bye
```